# Issue displaying data when passing props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand why this is throwing an error of name is undefined, but if I do it a different way, I can get data to display... Been stuck on this for quite awhile now and can't pass data to other components. This is the closest I've come, but don't know why one way works but the other says undefined. Trying to select and pass data from JobsTableApi.js to Title.js

**JobsTableApi.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import Title from './components/header/Title.js'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class JobsTableApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <div>
          {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => (
            <div key = {item}>
              {data["data"][item][6].value}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default JobsTableApi;
```

**Title.js:**

```
import { React } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import JobsTableApi from '../../JobsTableApi';

export default function Title() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h3>
        <JobsTableApi />
      </h3>
    </div>
  )
}

Title.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

The above methods display all data coming over from my api call that has the field ID of 6 accurately, but since i'm attempting to pull different fields over to different components, I need to set it as props, but when I do, I get errors and says undefined. Example below.

**JobsTableApi.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Title from './components/header/Title.js'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class JobsTableApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <div>
          {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => (
            <div key = {item}>
              <Title name = {data["data"][item][6].value} />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default JobsTableApi;
```

**Title.js:**

```
import { React } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
//import JobsTableApi from '../../JobsTableApi';

export default function Title({ name }) {
  return(
    <div>
      <h3>
        {name}
      </h3>
    </div>
  )
}

Title.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

As you can see from my api call in the 'body' I'm pulling over many fields with values. From here I need to send these throughout my app into different components to be used.

Right now I have 2 api call files in my src folder, then src>components>charts>MultipleLineCharts.js files. As well as src>components>header>Title.js

I'm wondering if I need to change my structure and make the Api Calls on a parent component? Instead of this as siblings? App.js in src is rendering all. Any advice or guidance on this would be appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like both would crash - you default `data` in state to `null` and in your first render you do this: `data["data"]`. This will always crash, as the API call is not made until the component has mounted into the DOM (and rendered first time).

`data["data"]` feels a bit odd - why not just set `data["data"]` into state when you get it back from the API and default `data` in state to `[]` - that way you can safely map over it in the first render?

Comment: This is the only way i've been able to render the values, not sure what else to do, If i default data in state to [] it throws errors as undefined. Then if I change ```{Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => (
            <div key = {item}>
              {data["data"][item][6].value}
            </div>``` at all, then I get nothing but errors as well.

Comment: Just re-read your code again. If you have `this.state = { data: {} };` and then in render do `Object.entries(this.state.data).map([key, value] => { ...do stuff with each KVP })` then it should work. Just make sure that in your API code you set the object from `data["data"]` into state that is returned from the API.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but If I attempt this I still get errors. errors with the syntax with that arrow function, and still errors if state is not set to null.

Comment: Sorry I missed the brackets around the `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If the components you need to send the data to are all direct children of this parent API fetching component, then in the interests of starting simple, you don't need to use anything like [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) - keep it simple and get it working, then iterate as required.

The moment you build out a complex component hierarchy and unrelated or deeply-nested components need access to the data, then you probably want to look at something like Context / Redux.

Comment: So right now they are not direct children of my api fetching components. I'm also wondering if it is a bad idea to just do these calls in my app.js that is rendering all of these children components, therefore I could pass the data to children without context or redux. Thoughts? I'm fairly unexperienced in react as you can see, but from my understanding it was better practice to have these api calls in separate files and just send the data when needed.

Comment: If it makes sense to fetch all data at once, then fetch it in a parent component and either pass it down via props, or use Context. If you can split up your API requests into smaller pieces, then you could fetch data in different components, only fetching what that needs. It really depends on what makes sense for your API(s), what components you want to show on screen at once etc. Lots of factors and no “right” answer. I’d start simple and fetch all in one place, pass down to other components via props and get it working…

Comment: …better to have something working that isn’t the most elegant, than deliberating too much over the what-ifs and having nothing to show for it. Once you have it working you can iterate and move towards context or a diff data fetching approach. By that stage you’ll feel way more comfortable to make those kinds of changes if needed.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'll attempt this and maybe split my API requests up into only what I need for those components. I'll look into changing the structure a little to accommodate this. Thanks Mike!

Comment: And the project is more of a simple software to display multiple line charts depicting data that already exists from the api calls, I just need to send that data over to the line chart components and set those to the line charts. so maybe smaller calls on each component might work.

Answer (score 0):

`Right now I have 2 api call files in my src folder, then src>components>charts>MultipleLineCharts.js files. As well as src>components>header>Title.js

I'm wondering if I need to change my structure and make the Api Calls on a parent component? Instead of this as siblings?
`

You can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for state management, So you can send or use data to any component.